# What should I store after a "Login using Facebook"

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

I've used the php-sdk to perform the login using facebook.  What should I store from the user so later requests (for example to get the user's friend lists or post a message) can be achieved?

The user id for sure.  Is there anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only Facebook user ID is required.

You can use Facebook id to get details of user and their friend list also.

Comment: Ok.  So I'll use my App's Key/Secret + the User id (that I got from the user's login) to perform the actions the user has allowed me to do on his/her behalf.   Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

You need the access_token, on top of the user ID

**Correction**

The SDK will store and send the access token automatically. So there's no need to store the access token yourself.

Comment: Be aware that the access_token will expire, unless you request the offline_access permission, and even then if the user changes his password or such, the token can still expire. So don't store the access_token in a database, but request it every time the user logs in and store it in the session.

Comment: For what reason? No, he need not

Comment: @MichaelH: fortunately `offline_access` is deprecated and will be removed soon! :3

Comment: @zerkms, Thanks for that. Was unaware that offline_access is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks.   So please check my last post on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can store users other details too if needed, like firstname, lastname, etc, but for actions like, getting user's friend lists or posting a message, you can only store the **user id** of the facebook logged in user. That is enough.